# How to set a rotation point on a nested SVG Element

Tags: html, css, svg, transform

**Recently,** I decided to experiment and learn about CSS Transforms. Now, I decided to try and make a common mobile button using SVG and a few transforms.

What I'm trying to do is to make the mobile button rotate 90 degrees with a transform origin on the very center of the element.

Here is my code:

```css
.mobileNav {
    display: block;
    transition: .5s;
  }
  
   .mobileNav:hover {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
     /*This is where the problem lies. How do I set the origin to the center of .mobileNav?? */
  }
 
ul {
    
    float: right;
    margin: 15px 50px 0px 0px;
  }
  
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    
    
    transition: .5s;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="mobileNav">
    <li>
     <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="10" height="20">
        <circle cx="5" cy="10" r="3"  stroke-width="4" fill="#333" />
        Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
     </svg> 
    </li>
    <li>
     <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="10" height="20">
        <circle cx="5" cy="10" r="3"  stroke-width="4" fill="#333" />
        Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
     </svg> 
    </li>
    <li>
     <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="10" height="20">
        <circle cx="5" cy="10" r="3"  stroke-width="4" fill="#333" />
        Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
     </svg> 
    </li>
    </ul>
```

**GOAL:** To set the transform origin to the center of .mobileNav.

**PROBLEM:** I am unable to achieve this.

**BROWSER:** My browser is **Firefox** 44.0.2

Comment: Oh...FF and SVG transforms...this again! Check out all the issues over on the right under "Related".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the default padding.  For added effect, you can also set the SVG and li's to not be display inline or inline-block.  Then float them so the align vertically. That should make it not as janky.

```css
body {padding: 3em;}
.mobileNav {
    display: block;
    transition: .5s;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
   .mobileNav:hover {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
     /*This is where the problem lies. How do I set the origin to the center of .mobileNav?? */
  }
 
ul {
    
    float: right;
    margin: 15px 50px 0px 0px;
  }
  
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    
    
    transition: .5s;
  }

 .mobileNav svg, .mobileNav li {
      display:block;
      float:left;
 }
```

```html
<ul class="mobileNav">
    <li>
     <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="10" height="20">
        <circle cx="5" cy="10" r="3"  stroke-width="4" fill="#333" />
        Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
     </svg> 
    </li>
    <li>
     <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="10" height="20">
        <circle cx="5" cy="10" r="3"  stroke-width="4" fill="#333" />
        Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
     </svg> 
    </li>
    <li>
     <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="10" height="20">
        <circle cx="5" cy="10" r="3"  stroke-width="4" fill="#333" />
        Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
     </svg> 
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, this will help alot

Answer (score 2):

`ul` has defaut `padding` or `margin` that needs a reset.

`li` and `svg` could be reset to `inline-block`.

Lets draw a border for debug to see where things stand.

`vertical-aign` + `line-height` will help to define an `height` to `ul` and will set childs at vertical middle.

```css
 body {
  margin-top:50px;/* snippet wants this */
 }

.mobileNav {
  display: block;
  transition: .5s;
  border: solid;
  padding: 0
}
.mobileNav:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 15px 50px 0px 0px;
  line-height: 1em;
}
li,
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mobileNav">
  <li>
    <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="10" height="20">
      <circle cx="5" cy="10" r="3" stroke-width="4" fill="#333" />Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
  </li>
  <li>
    <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="10" height="20">
      <circle cx="5" cy="10" r="3" stroke-width="4" fill="#333" />Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
  </li>
  <li>
    <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="10" height="20">
      <circle cx="5" cy="10" r="3" stroke-width="4" fill="#333" />Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
  </li>
</ul>
```